# counter_cache not updated in ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a js code that is run a like link is clicked (with ajax) - The link changes to unlike (with the proper route and method), and I want the likes_count which is a column in the model to be updated as well.

The thing is that the value doesn't get updated.
With no Ajax (full page load) - the value is OK

```
#create.js.erb
$("#like_link").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("artworks/unlike")) %>")
$("#likes").html('<%= @artwork.likes_count %>')

#relevant html snippet from the view
<div>
  Total likes: <span id="likes"><%= @artwork.likes_count %></span>  
</div>

#model - like.rb
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :artwork, :counter_cache => true
end
```

When using
`$("#likes").html('<%= @artwork.count %>')`
It works but missing the point of counter_cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your create method, exactly after saving your object, you should `reload` the object that you like it, something like this :

```
def create
    # some code
    if @like.save
        @artwork.reload # use reload to get the updated counter cache value
    end
end
```

Comment: nice! Thanks. I tried to add it in the js with no success... In the controller (actually in my case it is more correct to encapsulate it in the model method) it the right way. Thanks!